# Apache redirect from DMZ to internal networks

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I have a domains  test1.xxxxxx.com, test2.xxxxxx.com, test3.xxxxxx.com and so on which point to my DMZ ip address.

On my DMZ I have an apache web server.

The apache web server needs to redirect

```
test1.xxxxxx.com to test1.xxxxxx.com (192.168.1.1) on the internal network
test2.xxxxxx.com to test2.xxxxxx.com (192.168.1.2) on the internal network
test3.xxxxxx.com to test3.xxxxxx.com (192.168.1.3) on the internal network
```

The mapping for test1.xxxxxx.com to 192.168.1.1 and so on is specified in hosts file

I have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(test1.xxxxxx.com)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test1.xxxxxx.com [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(test2.xxxxxx.com)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test2.xxxxxx.com [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(test3.xxxxxx.com)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test3.xxxxxx.com [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to hit http://test1.xxxxxx.com in browser I get This webpage has a redirect loop

If I have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(test1.xxxxxx.com)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test2.xxxxxx.com [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Then the rewrite works.

Something similar used to work, but I changed my server and above does not work. What do I need to tweak to make this work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using 2 times the same domain. If test1.xxxxxx.com redirect to test1.xxxxxx.com that will still resolve to that dmz address (it's the same domain!) and loops till the browser decides it's enough :)

In your example where it "worked", you had different url on both lines test1.xxxxxx.com to test2.xxxxxx.com which resolves to different ip.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^test1\.xxxxxx\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         http://test1.xxxxxx.com/$1 [L,R,NE,P]
</VirtualHost>
```

Now works as I require it